# add project as reference?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

i want to add a 2 project as a reference to another project in C#

Comment: Is it from Visual Studio you want to do that?

Answer (score 3):

To add a project reference -

1.In Solution Explorer, select the project.

2.On the Project menu, choose Add Reference.The Add Reference dialog box opens.

3.Select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.

4.In the top pane, select the component you want to reference, and then click the Select button. Press CTRL while clicking to select multiple components.If the component you are looking for is not in the list, you may locate it using the Browse button.

5.Click OK when you have selected all the components you need.Selected references will appear under the References node of the project.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a solution with several projects and you want to add references between them.  If that is the case then you want to add a Project Reference.

- Right click on the project select "Add Reference"
- Select the Project Tab which will look like the following

[image]

- Select the project(s) and hit Ok

Answer (score 1):

i). If the other projects developed under .Net frame work

```
Solution Explorer --> Rigth Click the current project name -> Add reference -> Browse
```

Select the dlls

ii).  If the projects are not developed under .net framework then use

```
[DllImport("DllPath+DllName.dll")]
Methods()
```

Comment: Which file i should select to add the project as there is many files in this project , in bin & backup ...

Comment: If your Building the project from `Debug` then select `bin->Debug->ProjectName.dll` , else if from `Release` then `bin->Release->ProjectName.dll`

Comment: The dialogs have file type filters, they won't let you pick the wrong thing.